# Format the output in JAVA

Tags: java

I am little confused about how I can format my output cleanly like the output given below:

[image: Click here to see what output format I want]

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountChar {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("test1.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    int numCount = 0;
    int otherCount = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please specify the # of intervals: ");
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    while (true) {
      if (N == 2 || N == 4 || N == 5 || N == 10) {
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Your input is not supported, please choose another value: ");
        N = sc.nextInt();
      }

    }
    int interval_at = 100 / N;
    int[] histogram = new int[N];
    try {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      String text = null;
      while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        int num = 0;

        try {
          num = Integer.parseInt(text);
          if (num > 0 && num <= 100) {
            numCount++;
            int inRange = (num - 1) / interval_at;
            histogram[inRange] = histogram[inRange] + 1;
          } else {
            otherCount++;
          }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          otherCount++;
          continue;
        }
      }
      // creating a file in which the output is stored
      File myObj = new File("result1.txt");
      if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
      } else {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
      }

      // Writting in a file
      FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("result1.txt");
      myWriter.write("Please specify the # of intervals: ");
      myWriter.write("\n" + N);
      myWriter.write("\nNumber of integers in the interval [1,100]: " + numCount);
      myWriter.write("\nOthers: " + otherCount);
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        myWriter.write("\n" + ((i * interval_at) + 1) + " - " + ((i + 1) * interval_at) + " | ");
        for (int j = 0; j < histogram[i]; j++) {
          myWriter.write("*");
        }
      }
      myWriter.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My code output:

```
1 - 25 | ****************
26 - 50 | *******************
51 - 75 | ***********************
76 - 100 | **********************
```

I need to format my output as given in the picture above.

Comment: your question is not clear, please share complete code

Comment: what have you tried so far? I think a simple String concatenation with some spaces when needed, and a tab could do the trick here.

Comment: Post text here rather than images, wherever practical.

Comment: Edited, Now please check

Comment: @Stultuske i tried that to but it also not work

Comment: what's the content of test1.txt file?

Comment: how did you try that?

Comment: @Stultuske by giving spaces in the print statement

Comment: could you show that attempt in code in the question?